# Computing dimension over a field of rationals

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am looking to find the dimension the vector space $V$ over $\Bbb Q$, the field of rationals, where the vectors are real numbers of the form 
$p + q\sqrt 2$,  where $p$ and $q$ are rationals.

I'm thinking that the dimension is infinite, but having trouble with proving to myself that it is right (assuming I'm right in the first place).

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is your vector space?

Comment: the dimension is 2. They gave you a basis.

Comment: I saw this vectorspace in some other occasions too , does it have any important role in Algebra/Lin.Algebra ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 2.

Because of the way you defined your vector space, $1+0\sqrt{2}$ and $0+1\sqrt{2}$ generate it. So since they are independent over $\Bbb Q$, they form a basis.